# Probability of getting a king and queen without replacement

Tags: probability, card-games

The probability of getting drawing a king and queen from a deck of 52 cards without replacement is $\frac{4}{52} \frac{4}{51}$. I'm confused why it's not twice of this. We could achieve a king and queen in 2 different ways. First drawn card is a king and second drawn card is a queen, or first drawn card is a queen and second drawn card is a king. These are disjoint events, so wouldn't the probability actually be $\frac{4}{52} \frac{4}{51} + \frac{4}{52} \frac{4}{51}$?

I saw the first result left by the comment by tpb261 in [Probability in cards that $4$ people each get queen and king?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818829/probability-in-cards-that-4-people-each-get-queen-and-king).

Comment: You are right.  The probability of getting a King and  then a Queen, in that order,  is (4/52)(4/51).  The probability of getting a Queen and then a King, in that order, is also (4/52)(4/51).  The probability of getting a King and a Queen, in either order, is (4/52)(4/51)+ (4/52)(51) = 2(4/54)(4/51).

Comment: I agree with your analysis.  I'm not sure where you saw the half-sized answer, but it's possible the wording ot the problem originally suggested first draw a king and then draw a queen.

Comment: Not every comment on this site is correct.